# Is Reactor Context used only for statically initialised data?

Tags: project-reactor

Consider following 4 lines of code:

```
Mono<Void> result = personRepository.findByNameStartingWith("Alice")
                                    .map(...)
                                    .flatMap(...)
                                    .subscriberContext()
```

**Fictional Use Case which I hope you will immediately map to your real task requirement:**

How does one adds "Alice" to the context, so that after `.map()` where "Alice" is no longer `Person.class` but a `Cyborg.class` (assuming irreversible transformation), in `.flatMap()` I can access original "Alice" `Person.class`. We want to compare the strength of "Alice" person versus "Alice" cyborg inside `.flatMap()` and then send them both to the moon on a ship to build a colony.

- I've read about 3 times:
  https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context
- I've read dozen articles on `subscriberContext`
- I've looked at colleague code who uses subscriberContext but only for Tracing Context and MDM which are statically initialised outside of pipelines at the top of the code.

So the conclusion I am coming to is that something else was named as "context" , what majority can't use for the overwhelming use case above.

Do I have to stick to tuples and wrappers? Or I am totally dummy and there is a way. I need this context to work in entirely opposite direction :-), unless "this" context is not the context I need.

Comment: Reactive and functional programming encourage immutability. I think that's the primary reason why this is not possible (easily). Also, Reactor is an already quite complex beast. If you add a mutable context to the mix, it will quickly become a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I will await for Reactor developers attention (or later than that go to GitHub to raise an issue with the conceptual naming error, if I am correct) but in the meantime. I believed that Reactor Context could solve this:

[What is the efficient/proper way to flow multiple objects in reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721423/what-is-the-efficient-proper-way-to-flow-multiple-objects-in-reactor)

But what it actually reminds is some kind of mega closure over reactive pipeline propagating down->up and accepting values from outside in an imperative way, **which IMO is a very narrow and limited use case to be called a "context", which will confuse more people to come.**

Answer (score 0):

`Context` and subscribeContext in posts you refer to are indeed one and the same...

The goal of the `Context` is more along the lines of attaching some information to a given subscription.

This works because upon subscription, a chain of `Subscriber` is constructed to "materialize" the processing, and by nature each given operator (or step) as a reference to its downstream in order to be able to push data to it.

As a result, it can also query it for its view of what the current subscription `Context` is, hence the down-to-up approach.

Comment: Side note, it is not likely to be reversed and be mutable at runtime, little use in raising an issue asking for it.

Comment: Fair enough, I am highlighting the fact the this current implementation is extremely limited.

If I read this "The usual workaround for ThreadLocal usage is to move the contextual data, C, along your business data, T, in the sequence, by using (for instance) Tuple2<T, C>. This does not look good and leaks an orthogonal concern (the contextual data) into your method and Flux signatures." from the official docs. I am given a hint that it aims to replace ThreadLocal , where ThreadLocal due to nature of blocking programming is much more flexible than Context.

Comment: not sure if you've considered this, but one pattern is to add a mutable container to the `Context` if you want to change its content on the data path

Comment: mm, but that isn't any different to just using mutable container directly, it becomes really ugly, I guess I had some fantasies that somehow reactor would help me here, I am using mono.cache() then I map and flatMap this mono, and then I zipWith where I need this cached mono initial instance again. I know it sounds a bit stupid but at least I don't need to carry tuple over entire chain. Maybe you have better suggestion as I effectively need to teleport Mono/Flux to be available several operators later when the type already changed without TT (total tuplification :-D )